# View showoing a black space, but appears on Touch

Tags: android

I have this strange problem in my layout.I have a view whose visibility is `VISIBLE` and I can see it in **Hierarchyviewer**, but its not appearing on the screen! It shows only a blank space. But it is touchable and on touching the blank space, it corrects itself, the view appears and it's also handling touch event. It looks like some issue with refreshing the layout.

Please help if anybody has faced this issue?

**Note:** Its not behind any other view, its handling touch events as well].

Comment: @andruboy, This is a big layout. After some operations i entered this state. In anycase, how can a `VIEW` disappears but handles the touch?

Comment: @sujith we can't shoot an arrow in air. We will at least need to know some of xml and java :|